# Change language in DatePicker Ant Design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, localization, antd

I have some problem with change language of month and days in my DatePicker from Ant Design. I want my DatePicker looks like this: [want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymvJA.png)
I try to use this https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#Localization but it's not working as I want. It's change only "Today" on the bottom.
[myPicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLsvN.png)
My code: [imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6n10.png), [DatePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CamDx.png)

Comment: [Please read this for future questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question), do you have a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to share?